# How do I reset my display on the 2014 Sonata?

Tags: troubleshooting, sonata, bluetooth

I have a 2014 Sonata and the display switched off. I am unable to use the rearview camera, the radio and the bluetooth connection.

I had called the dealer who asked me to reset the display using a ballpoint pen or a pin. I could only find 1 point where the pin goes in. I have tried to reset, but I haven't had any luck. I wasn't able to find any info in the user manual.

Is this the right place, I am targeting?[image]

Comment: pretty sure that's the right place, but you'll need to hold it in for a good 5 or 10 count to make it reset... with key on

Comment: I will try again in the evening today

Comment: This has not worked, so now going to the dealer seems like the next step.

Comment: So I was not able to reset the computer in my Sonata. So I had to take it to the dealership. They have now ordered a new radio for the car. I am waiting on their phone call.

Comment: The new console has been put in. Everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to my 2006 Toyota Prius and I solved by pushing the "Display" button. Maybe the pushing the "DISP" button may do this job for you too.

Comment: I have tried the display button about 6 times now and it has not worked.